# How to Start a SQL insert query from failed step?

Tags: sql

I am running a Select query and getting lots of rows from it(sometimes more than 500) then inserting thoes values one by one into another table. Now i want to know which insert step failed so that i can start inserting from that failed step again so that table does not update with duplicate value.

Comment: You can wrap all the inserts into a single transaction.  Then they either all succeed or fail at the same time, and you don't need to restart at an arbitrary place.

Comment: Why are you inserting one at a time? Why not just do a single insert?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax may vary from system to system, however structure and process remains.
When one does database deployments to live system he prepares two SQL scripts.

1.Change script that has structure like this:

```
PRINT 'Doing X'

SCRIPT X 
....

GO

PRINT 'DOING Y'
SCRIPT Y
....

GO
```

2.Rollback script that reverts all the changes that section of script does.
Revert scripts are executed in reverse order.

```
REVERT SCRIPT Y

REVERT SCRIPT X
```

When change script fails you will know which section failed by the last message printed out, then you will take all sections of rollback script that run after the failed section and revert changes.